# How can I get a specific struct type returned?

Tags: swift

I want to initialize the struct by receiving the "struct type"(?) by a specific logic as below.
As I abstracted the return value of the struct into `MyProtocol` had a declaration of `init()`, which seems a little awkward.

I'm not sure I can do this.
I'd like to get an undecided struct type returned, what should I do?
Is this for the best?

For your information, `Opaque Type` is not available because it needs to support iOS 13 or earlier.

```swift
protocol MyProtocol {
    init() // Is this for the best?
}

struct AAA: MyProtocol {
    var numberAAA: Int // Sample variable.
    
    init() {
        print("init AAA")
        numberAAA = 100
    }
}

struct BBB: MyProtocol {
    var numberBBB: Int // Sample variable.
    
    init() {
        print("init BBB")
        numberBBB = 200
    }
}

class MyClass {
    
    func mainLogic() {
        let myStruct = randomStruct()
        myStruct.init() // This is the reason init () declared in the MyProtocol.
    }
    
    func randomStruct() -> MyProtocol.Type {
        if Bool.random() {
            return AAA.self
        } else {
            return BBB.self
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`init()` as a protocol requirement seems odd. No one is stopping you to do this and compiler should allow this, however I would consider making protocol based on some other requirement rather than just `init()`.

Here's an attempt to do so -

```
protocol NumberOperation {
    var number: Int { get set }
    mutating func perform()
}

struct Incrementer: NumberOperation {
    var number: Int
    mutating func perform() {
        number += 1
    }
}

struct Decrementer: NumberOperation {
    var number: Int
    mutating func perform() {
        number -= 1
    }
}

struct Record<O: NumberOperation> {
    public var operation: O
    mutating func perform() {
        operation.perform()
    }
}

class MyClass {
    
    func mainLogic() {
        var record = getRecord(type: Incrementer.self)
        record.perform()
    }
    
    func getRecord<O: NumberOperation>(type: O.Type) -> Record<O> {
        if type == Incrementer.self {
            return Record(operation: Incrementer(number: 1) as! O)
        }
        return Record(operation: Decrementer(number: 10) as! O)
    }
    
}
```

This introduces a container type `Record` that holds/wraps our type based on the same protocol conformation. This does the same what you were doing, probably is easier to read/understand.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.
I didn't just want two struct types. It was just a sample code for a simple question.

`randomStruct()` will return any struct type by Black-Box logic.
A particular structure type cannot be specified inside the `mainLogic()` function. (like `Incrementer.self`)
I just want to init it and use it.

If it was a class, it could simply have been returned to AnyObject.
Is there a better solution?